# Add new column with appropriate values from separate list

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to fill a new column with appropriate values from a list using `dplyr`. I tried to come up with a simple reproducible example, which can be found below. In short, I want to add a column "Param" to a dataframe, based on the values of the existing columns. The matching values are found in a separate list. I've tried functions as `ifelse()`and `switch` but I cannot make it work. Any tips on how this can be achieved?

Thank you in advance!

```r
library(dplyr)

# Dataframe to start with
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(rep("A", times = 3), 
                          rep("B", times = 3), 
                          rep(1:3, times = 2)), ncol = 2))

colnames(df) <- c("Method", "Type")
df
#>   Method Type
#> 1      A    1
#> 2      A    2
#> 3      A    3
#> 4      B    1
#> 5      B    2
#> 6      B    3

# Desired dataframe
desired <- cbind(df, Param = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4))
desired
#>   Method Type Param
#> 1      A    1   0.9
#> 2      A    2   0.8
#> 3      A    3   0.7
#> 4      B    1   0.6
#> 5      B    2   0.5
#> 6      B    3   0.4

# Failed attempt
param <- list("A" = c("1" = 0.9, "2" = 0.8, "3" = 0.7),
              "B" = c("1" = 0.6, "2" = 0.5, "3" = 0.4))

param
#> $A
#>   1   2   3 
#> 0.9 0.8 0.7 
#> 
#> $B
#>   1   2   3 
#> 0.6 0.5 0.4

df %>%
  mutate(Param = ifelse(.$Method == "A", param$A[[.$Type]],
                        ifelse(.$Method == "B", param$B[[.$Type]], NA)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Param`.
#> ℹ `Param = ifelse(...)`.
#> x attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Comment: Put your param values in a data.frame and join it with your original df. Also, you don't have to use matrix to fill values in a data.frame.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What do you mean specifically with "join it"? Right now, the values are in the right order and do not have to appear multiple times. In my real df, values will appear in random order and can appear multiple times. I'm not sure whether that was clear from my original question.

Comment: You could look into `merge` or `dplyr::left_join`... But both of these would require the param list to be a data.frame... the named list of named lists does not make sense to me (why not use a data.frame??)

Comment: It's just the way that it's defined in the code at the moment. I could (and probably will) convert it to a df as the suggested functions require this, but I have used something like ```df %>% mutate(Param = param[.$Type])``` before (where param is a vector instead of a list), which did the job. Instead of converting it to a df, I was wondering whether there was any way to just work with the objects that are already defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this could be cleaner, but it will get the job done: Option 1:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    Param = unlist(param)[
      match(
        paste0(
          df$Method, 
          df$Type
        ),
        names(
          do.call(
            c,
            lapply(
              param,
              names
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ]
  )
```

Option 2: (cleaner version):

```
df %>% 
  type.convert() %>% 
  left_join( 
    do.call(cbind, param) %>% 
      data.frame() %>%
      mutate(Type = as.integer(row.names(.))) %>% 
      pivot_longer(!Type, names_to = "Method", values_to = "Param"),
    by = c("Type", "Method")
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unlist your list and just add it to your df.

```
df$Param <- unlist(param)

  Method Type Param
1      A    1   0.9
2      A    2   0.8
3      A    3   0.7
4      B    1   0.6
5      B    2   0.5
6      B    3   0.4
```

Comment: beautiful, works because it's order the same way (+1).

Comment: Thank you. This would indeed work for the example I specified above. I was looking for something that would be more general (e.g., when the order deviates), which should have been specified more clearly in my question. My mistake.

Comment: You can order it with `df <- arrange(df, df$Method)`  and then use my answer if your list is ordered as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @dario including matching data in dataframe would be easier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  nest(data = Type) %>%
  left_join(stack(param) %>% nest(data1 = values), by = c('Method' = 'ind')) %>%
  unnest(c(data, data1))

# Method Type  values
#  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A      1        0.9
#2 A      2        0.8
#3 A      3        0.7
#4 B      1        0.6
#5 B      2        0.5
#6 B      3        0.4
```

Comment: Super clean ( +1)

Comment: I will indeed convert to a df as this is repeatedly mentioned. Thank you!